# То чувство, когда

Tags: синтаксис, синтаксический-разбор

> То самое чувство, когда ты круче всех.
>   То самое чувство, когда ты на волне.

Где здесь подлежащее и сказуемое?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Это предложение тесно связано  с предыдущим содержанием, например: И тогда тебя охватывает особое чувство. **То самое чувство, когда ты круче всех. То самое чувство, когда ты на волне.**

**Вариант 1**. Можно считать предложение неполным, тогда подлежащее "это" пропущено, а "чувство" – сказуемое.

**Вариант 2.** Можно  считать эту конструкцию **постпозитивным номинативом** со значением оценки или  раскрытия содержания. К номинативу относится  придаточное предложение (союз КОГДА).

**Примечание**

Союз  КОГДА может использоваться в придаточных изъяснительных предложениях, заменяя союз ЧТО. Хорошо, что все дома. Хорошо, когда все дома. **То самое чувство, что ты лучше всех.** То самое чувство, когда ты лучше всех.

Значение такое: То самое чувство, когда тебе кажется, что ты лучше всех.

Comment: Где здесь подлежащее и сказуемое?

Comment: Здесь нет сказуемого. Только номинатив и его распространитель в виде придаточного предложения. Другой вариант -  считать предложение неполным, тогда подлежащее "это" пропущено, а "чувство" - сказуемое.

Comment: Это не мой вопрос, если заметили.

Comment: Спасибо, я всё заметила и учла Вашу критику  Также я обратила внимание на ответы других участников.  Хотя они и не получили замечаний по содержанию ответов, но я не могу сказать, что эти ответы идеальны и что в них сделан грамматический разбор заданного предложения, то есть определен его тип и предикативная основа.

Comment: Sharon, пусть критика Вас не задевает :) Получился ведь в итоге по-настоящему хороший ответ. И примечание про конструкцию "то чувство, когда" совсем не очевидное и очень кстати.

Comment: Спасибо, я сначала действительно отвечала на немного другой вопрос (это номинатив или неполное предложение).  Критика была справедливой...

Answer (score 0):

Здесь нет сказуемых. Это не совсем полноценные предложения, они могут быть только продолжением какой-то мысли.

Answer (score 0):

Даже в незаконченном виде (без сказуемых) такие высказывания некорректны из-за нарушения стандартных связей: "то чувство, **которое**", "тот момент, **когда**". Варианты исправления:

> То самое чувство, которое возникает, когда тебе кажется, что ты круче всех...
>
> То самое чувство, которое возникает, когда ты на волне...
>
> Такое чувство, будто ты на волне (будто ты круче всех)...

Comment: Возможно, что здесь не о самом "чувстве" речь, поэтому и стоит "когда". "То самое чувство, когда ты на волне", мол: "вот, ты на волне - это то самое (желание, обстоятельство, показатель...)". Слово "чувство" в каком-то другом значении применено.

Comment: Это сбивчивая речь, человек выразился нескладно, хотя по набору слов можно догадаться о его ощущениях.

Comment: Я и говорю "возможно". Не смог подобрать точное слово и применил "чувство", а "когда" применил правильно. Такое бывает. Русский язык такое смешение допускает.